# How do I print out lines in a Ruby file that contains TAB character?

Tags: ruby

I have two files, "test1.rb", "test2.rb". "test1.rb" contains TAB (`"\t"`) characters at lines 82 and 84.

I want a print-out like this:

```
test1.rb: 82 (it means that there are TAB included in the line of 82).
test1.rb: 84 (it means that there are TAB included in the line of 84).
```

Answer (score 6):

```
def check_tab file
  open(file){|io| io.each_line.with_index(1){|s, l| puts "#{file}: #{l}" if s =~ /\t/}}
end
%w[test1.rb test2.rb].each{|f| check_tab(f)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
["test1.rb", "test2.rb"].each do |fn|
  File.foreach(fn) do |li|
    puts "#{ fn }: #{ $. }" if li["\t"]
  end
end
```

`$.` means "the current line number in the file being read".